# Moving files/creating folders shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm attempting to move files in a directory to another directory based on file names. File names will be `COMPANY-ReportType_timestamp`.

I'm currently using this to make the directories:

```
for i in *
        do mkdir /mnt/folder/"${i%-*}"
           mkdir /mnt/folder/"${i%-*}"/"${i%_*}"
done
```

and using this to move the files:

```
for i in *
        do mv $i /mnt/folder/"${i%-*}"/"${i%_*}"
done
```

In this script, it will create the "COMPANY" folder and then "COMPANY-ReportType" folder within it. If I could parse the "Company-" from the subfolder, that'd be great. However, I was just given a twist on this whole process.

Sometimes, they won't provide a specific ReportType and will simply have COMPANY-blahblahtimestamp. In this case, they want it moved to the root of the COMPANY folder. Any ideas on how to do this??

I appreciate the help on this! I've tried a few variations but still not quite right. Hoping if I put a little more info it will help...:

Files I have to move:

Company-Report1_yyyymmdd
Company-Report2_yyyymmdd
Company-Filenameyyyymmdd
Company-Filename-yyyymmdd

The outcome I need is a Company folder created, if it doesn't already exist. Then folders for Report1 and Report2 created under the Company and then the Report1 and Report2 files moved into their folders. Then move the two files without the _ into the root of the Company folder.

Again, thank you so much for your help on this! I appreciate it! (and thank you for pointing out what your variables are doing so I can better understand them!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix (it can handle more deep subfolders)

```
for i in *
do 
  folder=${i%_*}                          # folder = COMPANY-ReportType
  folder="/mnt/folder/${folder//-//}"     # folder = /mnt/folder/COMPANY/ReportType
  mkdir -p "${folder}"     # mkdir with -p option: no error if existing, make parent directories as needed exist or not.
  mv "$i" "${folder}"      
done
```

New edit after new request:

```
for i in *               # sample as: Company-Report1_yyyymmdd Company-Report2_yyyymmdd Company-Filenameyyyymmdd Company-Filename-yyyymmdd
do
  if [[ "$i" =~ _ ]]; then                   # check if the file name has "_" or not.
     folder=${i%_*}                          # folder = COMPANY-ReportType
     folder="/mnt/folder/${folder//-//}"     # folder = /mnt/folder/COMPANY/ReportType
  else
     folder="/mnt/folder/${i%%-*}"           # folder = /mnt/folder/COMPANY
  fi

  mkdir -p "${folder}"     # mkdir with -p option: no error if existing, make parent directories as needed exist or not.
  mv "$i" "${folder}"
done

mkdir -p /mnt/folder/Company/Report1
mv Company-Report1_yyyymmdd /mnt/folder/Company/Report1
mkdir -p /mnt/folder/Company/Report2
mv Company-Report2_yyyymmdd /mnt/folder/Company/Report2
mkdir -p /mnt/folder/Company
mv Company-Filenameyyyymmdd /mnt/folder/Company
mkdir -p /mnt/folder/Company
mv Company-Filename-yyyymmdd /mnt/folder/Company
```

Comment: Thanks BMW! That works pretty well but it creates folders for everything. I'm still new to shell scripting and need to learn more about the variables... (tried modifying your script a bit and it just went downhill) - I just edited my original post to try to better describe what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I tinkered around with this one and the reports moved to the root won't need to be done. This one will work perfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Name your variables

```
for i in *
do
        company=${i%-*}
        rest=${i#*-}
        type=${rest%_*}
        name=${rest#*_}
        if [ $type -eq $name]; then # No report type
             mkdir -p /mnt/folder/$company
             mv $i /mnt/folder/$company/$name
        else
             mkdir -p /mnt/folder/$company/$type
             mv $i /mnt/folder/$company/$type/$name
        fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, when attempting to run the script I'm getting a syntax error on the company= line

Comment: I missed `do` keyword after `for`

Comment: Thanks Raul - I did try it again but got an error: line 7: [: missing `]' So I added a space after "$name" and then got an error stating: [: *: integer expression expected